# How can I access an object inside and array in Laravel PHP?

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, collections

I am returning an array using query builder, and I want to access its object only, not the whole array.

Here is the query

```
$data = ($request->props[0]);
$index = DB::table('produits')
    ->select('sous_categorie_id')
    ->where('product_type', 'like', $data)
    ->get();
return $index;
```

The results that I am getting:

```
[{
    "sous_categorie_id":7
}]
```

What am trying to get:

```
[
    7, 
]
```

I tried Model Query but I am not so familiar with it, so I have hit a wall here so I need help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side comment: you should not have columns in another language than english, and try to use Relationships/Models as much as possible, why use `DB::table('produits')` when you should use `Product::xxx`... Stick to the Laravel standards and normalize your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck) method in Laravel.

```
$data = $request->props[0];
$index = DB::table('produits')
    ->select('sous_categorie_id')
    ->where('product_type', 'like', $data)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('sous_categorie_id');

return $index;
```

Comment: Sidenote, `->get()` is optional here; `DB::table(...)->pluck(...)` will have the same results as `DB::table(...)->get()->pluck('...')`